# Why does an ajax request not trigger validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form which is dynamically generated. Inside the form is a function that executes an AJAX request, and on success, modifies the value( sets it to an empty string)  of a hidden field which is used for validation.( The hidden field is set to "required:true" )

However, on successful execution of the function, the hidden field does not trigger jQuery's validation and i am able to submit the form. The validation of the hidden field is only triggered when i trigger the validation of other fields intentionally, and the error message for the hidden field will appear, together with the other error message.

Function:

```
function DeleteImageDP(){

    var itemid=$('#DisplayDeleteItemID').val();
    var filepath=$('#DisplayDeleteFilePath').val();
    var itempicid=$('#DisplayDeleteItemPicID').val();
    var cfm=confirm("Confirm deletion of picture? ( Note: Picture wil be deleted permanently.");
    if(cfm == true)
    {
        $.ajax({

        url:"delete/deletedp.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"ItemID="+itemid+"&FilePath="+filepath+"&ItemPicID="+itempicid,
        success:function(){

            alert("Image successfully deleted.");
            $('#ImagePreviewDP').prop('src','').hide();
            $('#ImagePreviewDPValidate').val('');
            $('#DisplayDelete').hide();

        },
        error:function(){

            alert("Image could not be deleted due to an error.");

        }

        });
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

};
```

Validation:

```
$('#ItemDetailsContainer').on('change',function(){
    //Validation code .....
    ImagePreviewDP:{
        required:true
    },
    //More validation code....
});
```

Form(extract):

```
//Input and preview for Display Pic
echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails' >";
    //More code above
    echo"<img id=ImagePreviewDP name=ImagePreviewDP class='ImagePreview' src=\"$dp\" > ";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id='ImagePreviewDPValidate' name='ImagePreviewDPValidate' value=\"$dp\" >";
    //More code below
echo"</div>";
```

Why doesn't setting the value of $("#ImagePreviewDP") to an empty string trigger the on.change?Also how would i get the validation to trigger upon successful execution of the function instead of it only triggering together with other errors?

Comment: you have to subscribe to the change event of `#ItemDetailsContainer` after it loaded.

Comment: What is the element with the id `ItemDetailsContainer`? You haven't shown that in your HTML. From the name, it sounds like a div, which I don't believe has a native `change` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically setting an elements value with javascript never triggers the `onchange` event, you have to trigger it yourself

```
$.ajax({

    url:"delete/deletedp.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"ItemID="+itemid+"&FilePath="+filepath+"&ItemPicID="+itempicid,
    success:function(){

        alert("Image successfully deleted.");
        $('#ImagePreviewDP').prop('src','').hide();
        $('#ImagePreviewDPValidate').val('');
        $('#DisplayDelete').hide();

        $('#ItemDetailsContainer').trigger('change');
    //     ^^ trigger event handler

    },
 ...........
```